# MYSQL, combination of WHERE/LIMIT/ ORDERBY

Tags: mysql, limit, where-clause

I have this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_event WHERE DATE(edate) >= DATE(NOW())';
   $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
   $news = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

which runs fine
however when I change it to this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_event WHERE DATE(edate) >= DATE(NOW() LIMIT 2)';
```

I get this error message

```
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /var/www/.../...php
```

Finally I would like to combine it with order by
that is something like this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_event WHERE DATE(edate) >= DATE(NOW() LIMIT 2 ORDER BY DESC)';
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pull the limit clause out of the DATE() macro.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_event WHERE DATE(edate) >= DATE(NOW()) LIMIT 2
```

Also if you want to order you have to set a field, like

```
SELECT * FROM tb_event WHERE DATE(edate) >= DATE(NOW()) LIMIT 2 ORDER BY myField DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_event WHERE DATE(edate) >= DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY edate DESC LIMIT 2';
```

Note that the actual error you get is in how you are calling `mysqli_error` in the error processing code. Fix this too.